# resolution of 2 same domain names with different extensionson same server causes problem

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Seems i have an issue with name resolution in xampp apache. Neither site will display the folders to which they are assigned.
This is what i have in my httpd-vhosts file for the two domains...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.ca
    DocumentRoot "C:/SERVr/htdocs/__WWW__/example.ca"
    ServerName example.ca
    ErrorLog "logs/example.ca-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/example.ca-access.log" common
    <Directory "C:/SERVr/htdocs/__WWW__/example.ca/">

</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/SERVr/htdocs/__WWW__/example.com"
    ServerName example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/example.com-access.log" common
    <Directory "C:/SERVr/htdocs/__WWW__/example.com/">

</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Subfolders display without an issue, displaying the correct folders, but the main pages on both domains go to Index of/. I have seen such an issue in a post on SO many years ago, but cannot find that article any more.

On this server i have 8 other domains... all resolve correctly to the proper folders, only these 2 seem to go nowhere.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: do you have index.html or index.php under example.ca and example.com folders? otherwise what do you mean by but the main pages on both domains go to Index of/?

Comment: Both folders have their own index.php, both different pages. They go to what appears to be an empty folder. Does not go to the htdocs main folder either.